# How can I get a Compaq CQ62-231NR to boot up with Hard Drive error?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, bios, compaq-laptop

I'm a software engineer, but everyone I know thinks I have the ability to fix any computer problem, so, a friend gave me their Compaq CQ62-231NR laptop, which won't boot up. He bought it used from someone else, so has no warranty, etc., but the machine is barely used - it's obviously close to brand new.

When booting, or testing the hard drive in the BIOS, it throws an error.

I've tried booting from a Windows 7 boot CD made on another machine. This gets me a little further. It shows the Microsoft Corporation/green progress bar screen for a few minutes, then goes black for a few minutes, then I see the white Windows arrow cursor, and it just sits like that forever - I let it sit for a couple days like that with no change.

Any suggestion on how to get this thing running again?

Comment: Press F8 while rebooting it and select "Last Known Good Configuration" from the menu.

Comment: F8 does nothing for me

Comment: Are you **SURE** there's no warranty? http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/weInput?cc=us&lc=en Sounds like a RAM issue, best guess.

Comment: Memory Test passes when it's run in the BIOS.

Comment: @EricBelair Please edit you question to include the full and exact error message on boot.

Comment: Run the hard drive test from the bios and post any error codes or messages.

Comment: FYI @Chris, it IS out of warranty. Thank you for the link.